# How to break line in Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to break line to show text in next line but its now working using nbreak var

tried giving the "//n" as well instead of assign var but its not working any help what i am missing here

```
function GetOrgJSON(employeeList,manager,total){
    var nbreak = '\\n';
    var note = '';
    var employeeProcessed=[];
    for(var i=0;i<employeeList.length;i++){
        
        var objEmp = employeeList[i];      
        if(objEmp.Manager == manager && employeeProcessed.indexOf(objEmp.Name) < 0 ){
            var empUl = GetOrgJSON(employeeList,objEmp.ID,0);
            var tcount=0;
            if(empUl !=""){
            tcount=JSON.parse('[' + empUl + ']').length;
            } 
            
            note += '{"name":"'+objEmp.Name+'   '+tcount+' '+nbreak+'  '+objEmp.MainRole+' '+nbreak+' '+objEmp.Country+'",';
            note += '"Email":"'+objEmp.Email+'",';
            note += '"title":"'+objEmp.Designation+'"';
            
            employeeProcessed.push(objEmp.Name);
            
            //var empUl = GetOrgJSON(employeeList,objEmp.ID,0);
            
            if(empUl !=""){
                //total+=JSON.parse('[' + empUl + ']').length; 
                note +=',"children": [' + empUl + ']';
            }
            note +='},';
        }       
    } 
    note=note.slice(0,note.length-1);
    return note;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please, try to use only `\n`.
When you write `\\n` you are escaping it and it's taken as plain text.

Comment: I tried but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using \n like this. Please find the sample code with the same format as yours.

```
var nbreak = '\n';
var note = '{"name":"dsdds dfd '+nbreak+'  fdfd",';
note += '"Email":"hello",';
alert(note);
```